# Monkey patching: Does define_method take precedence over bind?

Tags: ruby

In the below code snippet, I monkey patch `Foo#bar` with a `define_method` block. After I initialize a new instance of `Foo`, I overwrite it with a `bind` call to the parent class `bar` method, but when I call the method the block defined by the `define_method` block is called. Why doesn't the `bind` call change the behavior of the method?

```
class OriginalFoo
  def bar
    puts 'in OriginalFoo!'
  end
end

class Foo < OriginalFoo
  def bar
    puts 'in Foo'
  end
end

class Foo < OriginalFoo
  old_bar = instance_method(:bar)
  define_method(:bar) do
    puts 'in define_method block'
    old_bar.bind(self).call
  end
end

foo_instance = Foo.new # => #<Foo:0x00007fe3ff037038>
OriginalFoo.instance_method(:bar).bind(foo_instance) # => #<Method: OriginalFoo#bar>
foo_instance.bar
# >> in define_method block
# >> in Foo
```

Comment: Are you asking why `OriginalFoo.instance_method(:bar).bind(foo_instance)` doesn't have any apparent effect?

Comment: @muistooshort: I suppose, this question is inspired by something like [this post](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/method-binding-in-ruby.html), which does indeed suggest that it should have this ettect.

Comment: Note: the define_method/patching is irrelevant (does not alter what's happening, in any way). Even if you comment it out, this code still will not print "in OriginalFoo!".

Comment: But you're not doing anything with the `Method` instance that `OriginalFoo.instance_method(:bar).bind(foo_instance)` returns, you're just throwing it away.

Comment: @muistooshort: JFC, how did I miss that?? Ok, bed time :)

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding what `bind` does. I thought it mutated the object that you called `bind` on, but it does not appear to actually do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how [`UnboundMethod#bind`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) works. You call [`Module#instance_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) to get an `UnboundMethod` (i.e. a method without a `self`):

```
OriginalFoo.instance_method(:bar)
# #<UnboundMethod: ... >
```

Then you call `UnboundMethod#bind` to attach a `self` to that method, that *returns* a `Method` instance:

```
m = OriginalFoo.instance_method(:bar).bind(foo_instance)
# => #<Method: ...>
```

But that won't alter the method in `foo_instance`, all it does is make `self` your `foo_instance` when (or if) you said `m.call`: `um.bind(obj)` doesn't do anything to `obj`, it just gives you `um` as a `Method` that has `obj` as its `self`.